# Sass source maps not showing in Chrome, running on MAMP Pro

Tags: google-chrome, sass

I have seen the question of source maps not being displayed in Chrome answered a few times, none of these quite cover my issue or set up.

I am running MAMP Pro as my local web server and am sure the problem isn't there, Safari and Firefox are showing the source maps for my sass project. This problem started in Chrome on my Mac last week.

My Chrome  Dev settings have Enable CSS source maps checked.

Inspector is still showing only the generated style.css file as the source.

The Gulp task I'm running to generate the source maps is:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: 'expanded', 
    indentType: 'tab',
    indentWidth: '1'
}).on('error', sass.logError))
.pipe(postcss([
    autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
]))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
.pipe(gulp.dest(root));
```

});

I'd really appreciate any help on getting this working, Chrome is my preferred dev browser.

Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I I made a really simple mistake. The gulp file was outputting the source maps to a folder outside of the project I had my webserver pointed at. I changed the code and the source maps are now working.